# Add XML as value to Web.Config

Tags: c#, xml, web-config

There is an `<appSettings>` section in myWeb.config
it contains a pairs like  `<add key="app:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />`
the string and bool values works perfect, but how to add an XML as value?

```
<taskDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/iis/media/v4/TM/TaskDefinition#">
    <name>Smooth Streams to Apple HTTP Live Streams</name>
    <description xml:lang="en"/>
    <inputDirectory/>
    <outputFolder/>
    <properties namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/iis/media/AppleHTTP#" prefix="hls">
        <property name="maxbitrate" value="10000000"/>
        <property name="segment" value="10"/>
        <property name="encrypt" value="false"/>
        <property name="pid" value=""/>
        <property name="codecs" value="false"/>
        <property name="backwardcompatible" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowcaching" value="true"/>
        <property name="passphrase" value=""/>
        <property name="key" value=""/>
        <property name="keyuri" value=""/>
        <property name="overwrite" value="true"/>
    </properties>
    <taskCode>
        <type>Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.SmoothToHLS.SmoothToHLSTask, Microsoft.Web.Media.TransformManager.SmoothToHLS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234aabbb1111</type>
    </taskCode>
</taskDefinition>
```

I have tried to change `< to &lt; > to &gt, & to &amp;, " to &quote;` but there are still not valid value for the string. how to encode this XML setting into proper value string?

Comment: Why not just store the XML in a separate file and put the file name as the value in an appSettings key?  Storing XML inside of another XML attribute seems like an antipattern.

Comment: This makes very little sense and it isn't clear what you are asking for. Are you trying to have a value attribute that is set to XML? You are talking about the `<appSettings>` section of your config file but your code sample doesn't include that. What are you really trying to do? Could you include the xml that you have that isn't working how you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters have said, not sure why you want to put it into the web.config as appose to a separate file specifically for this, but why not store it as a Base64 string.  And decode it when you need it.

If you are going to do this, hopefully it is only to read.  The web.config is a special file to IIS, when IIS sees that the file has been modified (programmatically or otherwise) it will reset the App Pool.

Comment: Answering a totally undefined question doesn't really seem useful, why post an answer before it is clarified?

Comment: @KevinWells While the question is a bit vague on why he wants to do it, what I got was "how do I store XML as a value in the web.config"  This I answered (base64 encoding) and mentioned one of my concerns when dealing with the web.config file.